# Angular Subject.Next Not Being Detected

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following bits of code. I can see that the first two parts seem to work correctly, bu the third bit that reacts to the variable change never happens. Any ideas?

The service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ConversationService {
    private convoIdSource = new Subject<number>();

    convoIdChanged = this.convoIdSource.asObservable();

    changeConvo(newConvoId: number){        
        this.convoIdSource.next(newConvoId);
    }
}
```

The change

```
openTeamChat(chatId: number){
    this.convoService.changeConvo(chatId);
}
```

The supposed detection

```
convoService.convoIdChanged.subscribe(convoId => {
    console.log(convoId);
    this.convoId = convoId;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had two different instances of the service, so they weren't in sync. I had to move the provider declaration all the way out to app.module.ts